# What's this symbol in the picture (a line across three notes with a '3' in the middle of the line)?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, tuplet

[image]

What does that 3 with lines stand for?

Answer (score 8):

It's a triplet.  It means that you should play the three notes indicated in the amount of time that you would normally take to play two.

This means that the three crotchets/quarter notes take the same time to play as the one minim/half note below.

Answer (score 3):

It means that you play the three crotchets (quarter-notes) in the time that would usually be taken by two.

Or to put it another way, the B F# G will take the same time as the D# underneath.

It's called a triplet.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I'm English so have to convert to fraction-notes on the rare occasion I use that nomenclature.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this piece is in 4/4 time. The -3- indicates triplets. Specifically quarter note triplets. 
Starting on beat 3 you should play 3 notes spread out over 2 beats.